# two NIC's on ubuntu server cannot resolve

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have two Nics on server:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.137.66.69
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.137.15.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.137.15.1
```

-10.137.15.X is where we want our web server/SSH/FTP to respond. We want it separate from the 10.137.66.x for security. No access to the .66 or eth0

-10.137.66.x is our corp network that we will use to access the server while in the network.

We have mysql/apache/ssh etc all listening on all interfaces.

How its behaving:

WHILE ON CORP NET: I have access to our site, SSH and etc. The server can ping 8.8.8.8. WHEN OUTSIDE NETWORK: I cannot access any thing.

If I run: sudo route add default gw 10.137.15.1 eth1 I get access from the outside & inside. HOWEVER, now the server itself cannot ping/access/resolv to the outside. Which is a problem for PHP and other web services on the server.

Can someone give me direction or show an proper config for what I am wanting pretty please?

Comment: I am thinking router does not have NAT turned on for the .15 network? Someone else manages our router...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to run "sudo route add default gw 10.137.15.1 eth1" I can only assume you have another default route set by default (although in your conf you have the same 10.137.15.1).

So I assume you have a default gw on eth0 say 10.137.66.1 which is probably the ip of your router.
which does NAT for the IP class 10.137.66.0/24

Since your ubuntu has eth0 in thet network, the router will nat 10.137.66.69 and you whill have access to the Internet (8.8.8.8).

Now, on the other side of your ubuntu (eth1) all computers must have 10.137.15.20 (eth0) as default gw and your ubuntu must act like a router. So you have to enable ip forwarding (to allow packets to pass from one interface to another) and use iptables to perform NAT.

It is pointless to set default gateway to 10.137.15.1 unless you have a router with that IP that can perform NAT for the .15.0/24 network.

Comment: Thanks after thinking about it over the weekend, I sort of thought the same thing, but you put it more elegantly.